# Spring Data Cassandra page-size vs fetch-size

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

What is the difference between page-size and fetch-size in Spring Data Cassandra?

The [current docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#spring.data.cassandra.request.page-size) show `page-size` as a property; but [2.1 docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) show `fetch-size`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `CassandraProperties` class, [`fetch-size`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraProperties.html#getFetchSize--) was deprecated in favor of `page-size` in version 2.3 and removed in version 2.5.